# App.Xaml.cs and MainPage.xaml.cs cannot be included in Solutions Explorer of Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2017

App.Xaml.cs and MainPage.xaml.cs cannot be included in my Xamarin Application's Solution Explorer of Visual Studio Community Edition 2017, while those are there in the Containing Folders of the Windows.

[image]

Comment: The error is pretty clear. If the `App()` class exists, press CTRL+. to see list of available options and reference the class accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The error says, its not able to find out the App() in the Xamarin Forms project. In the Image you shared there is no App.xaml and its .cs class files. Hence while calling the LoadApplication(new App()) from Android and iOS projects, it throws error.

If it is available in the Windows folder, you can delete those files and try adding a new App.xaml file in the Forms project. Once it is done you can clean the solution and do a rebuild.